# AngularJS - Problema con ngRequired y condición undefined

Tags: angularjs

Siempre he usado la directiva ngRequired con una condición con undefined para indicar que si una variable es distinta a undefined que haga que el campo del formulario sea obligatorio.

```
<input type="text" name="variable" id="variable" ng-model="variable" 
ng-disabled="variable === undefined" ng-required="variable !== undefined">
```

En mis 3 años con AngularJS (Angular 1) nunca he tenido problema con esta directiva, pero ahora me empieza a fallar y no consigo entender por qué. El problema que me da es que, por alguna razón, entra en bucle la directiva cambiando el valor de la "variable" entre el valor que le doy por defecto y undefined hasta que bloquea el navegador; sin embargo si le pongo distinto a null, por ejemplo, no tiene este comportamiento.

El error que me da la consola del navegador es:

```
    Uncaught Error: [$rootScope: infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.
Aborting!Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [
        [{
            "msg": "fn: function () {        var start = perf.now(); var ret = thatScope.$eval(watchExpression); var end = perf.now(); _digestEvents.push({ eventType: 'scope:watch', id: scopeId, watch: watchStr, time: end - start}); return ret;}",
            "newVal": true,
            "oldVal": false
        }, {
            "msg": "fn: function () {var start = perf.now();var ret = watchExpression.apply(this, arguments); var end = perf.now();  _digestEvents.push({eventType: 'scope:watch',id: scopeId,watch: watchStr,        time: end - start});return ret;}",
            "newVal": ""
        }, {
            "msg": "fn: function () { var start = perf.now();var ret = thatScope.$eval(watchExpression);var end = perf.now();_digestEvents.push({eventType: 'scope:watch',id: scopeId,watch: watchStr,time: end - start});return ret;}",
            "newVal": true,
            "oldVal": false
        }, {
            "msg": "fn: function () {var start = perf.now();var ret = thatScope.$eval(watchExpression);var end = perf.now();_digestEvents.push({ eventType: 'scope:watch',id: scopeId,watch: watchStr,time: end - start});return ret;}",
            "newVal": true,
            "oldVal": false
        }],
        [{
                "msg": "fn: function () {var start = perf.now();var ret = thatScope.$eval(watchExpression);
```

Por lo que puedo ver es algún problema con el $watch de la directiva pero no entiendo que me cambie el valor de mi variable entre el valor que le doy yo y el undefined.

Si a alguien le ha pasado algo similar o sabe cómo arreglarlo se lo agradecería, no se me ocurre nada para solventar esto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Paula. Te agradecería que en vez de ponernos imágenes de tu error, nos pusieras el código de tu error directamente en el post. Al ser un Log grande, copia las 5 o 6 primeras líneas de tu error, que normalmente son descriptivas.

Comment: Hola, vale lo cambio, es la primera vez que pregunto ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que tiene que ver con el two way data binding y el ciclo digestivo de angular.

Yo te recomiendo que no hagas ese tipo de comparación en la propia vista, si no que la delegues en una función que tengas en el controlador.

Como principal ventaja, está que en caso de fallo (como es tu caso) es mucho más fácil depurarla en el código, ya que en la vista **creo** y digo **creo** que no hay ningún debugger.

Además, queda mucho más "saneado" y limpio el código.

Lo que te digo es lo siguiente.

Vista:

```
<input type="text" name="variable" id="variable" ng-model="variable" ng-disabled="isVariableDisabled()" ng-required="isVariableRequired()">
```

Controlador:

```
$scope.isVariableDisabled = () => { // lo que tengas que hacer };
$scope.isVariableRequired = () => { // lo que tengas que hacer };
```

Espero que depurando eso, al menos te ayude a encontrar el error.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, también hice eso, me monté una función para ver si la variable que dentro del código, después de una respuesta de back cambiaba la variable de undefined a "" me lo comprobara y vi lo que comentaba, entra en la función una vez con la variable con valor "" y otra vez con undefined. Me puse a depurar para ver donde podría estar cambiando yo el valor, pero en ningún momento pongo la variable a undefined.

Comment: Por alguna razón el watch que hace angular en la directiva del ngRequired no le gusta esa comprobación de undefined.
En versiones antiguas de angular como la 1.2.9 funciona perfectamente la condición que puse arriba, pero ahora no le gusta.
Lo que he hecho es depender de otro parámetro que me van a pasar desde back para evitar este bucle con el ngRequired y que creo que va a ser más lógico (que me indiquen con true o false los campos que quieran habilitar y que sean obligatorios).

Comment: Muchas gracias.